# Why there's a difference between the two common appearances of the letter “a”?

Tags: typography

Luckily the forum is using Georgia typeface, so both can be easily shown below:

> ***a*** vs **a**

Comment: I’m a little too tired to pull these together into an answer at the moment, but for someone with more energy: the term for this distinction is *double-storey* vs. *single-storey* (or *double-storied*, etc.); historically, it comes from how the letter evolved in two different ways in different writing traditions, which then both got incorporated into typography; and there’s a lot of interesting info on this in various threads on the typophile forums, eg [here](http://typophile.com/node/10040).

Comment: Cyrillic has [a ton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_alphabet#Letterforms_and_typography) of such differences.

Comment: This is an interesting typography question, but unfortunately not an English question.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I suppose you can pretty much get your answer by considering how you managed to generate the two different forms in your post - ***a*** ***normally occurs in italic fonts***, whereas a is more normal in standard print fonts.

The italic form is just easier to use in handwriting, I guess. Similar flourishes and such occur in the "print" form for other letters - many fonts have a particularly ornate lower-case **g** that you normally wouldn't try to reproduce by hand.

Comment: I've seen some books for young children printed in a roman (not italic) typeface, but with italic-style glyphs for 'a', 'g' and 'y'. I can see why they did it, but I found them very odd to look at. (Actually, the font I see comments in here has this property for 'g' and 'y', but not for 'a'.)